# How to specify column names

Tags: python, pandas

I use the following code to get the count of months in a data set

```
crime_rate_month = crime_data["Month"].value_counts().to_frame()
print(crime_rate_month)
```

I want to specify "Month" and the "Count" as the titles of the resulting columns. How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: As per the suggested duplicate, you can use: `crime_data["Month"].value_counts().rename_axis('Month').reset_index(name='Count')`

Comment: @ouroboros1 This works. Could you also tell me how can I remove the index column?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `name` and `names` parameters of [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) respectively.

Try this :

```
crime_rate_month = (
                    crime_data["Month"].value_counts()
                        .to_frame(name="Count")
                        .reset_index(names=["Month"])
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename` to rename the resulting column:

```
crime_rate_month = crime_rate_month.rename(columns={
    "Month": "Count"
})
```